# Can we Filter PriceBook's while choosing the PriceBook on Opportunity

Tags: standardlayout

I have a requirement when we click on the `"Choose PriceBook"` button on Opportunity detail page under OpportunityProduct section we should get only filtered PriceBook based on 1 custom field of Opportunity

**Opportunity Detail Page**
[image]

**PriceBook Selection standard Page**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, you can't do this. Price Books are filtered based on your Organization Wide Defaults for Price Books and Price Book Shares. If you want to do anything fancier, you can write a custom Visualforce page and override the Choose Price Book button. To do this, go to Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Opportunity Products > Buttons and Links > Edit (ChoosePricebook) and specify the Visualforce page. The page itself must use the Opportunity Standard Controller:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="ChoosePricebookExtension">
  ...
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yes I do know that we can override the standard with a Visualforce page but using that what standard feature we'll be loosing?

Comment: We'll have to handle all the logic of deselecting a pricebook should delete all the lineItem

Comment: Okay that means if we remove the PriceBook2Id from opportunity it will auto delete the LineItem right?

Comment: Currently when we choose the PriceBook and Save it redirects to Add Product page how do we handle this in VF Page do we need to redirect to the standard URL

Comment: @RCS Yes, you'll probably want to redirect to the standard Add Products page. And yes, changing the Price Book wipes out the line items for you. You'll need to do some research if you choose this approach. It's doable, and not *too* challenging, but you'll need to do some homework.

Comment: It's simple page, but I wouldn't recommend for overriding this basic standard functionality. It will probably cost you in future. Possible other solution is to setup (with trigger or process builder) default price book. You can setup field in the Account that will define the default per each account and then use it